# Why we used 128 bytes internal RAM memory instead of 256 bytes in 8051?

Tags: microcontroller, memory, 8051

... since using 7-bit in 8-bit address bus wastes one wire.

In 8051 there is a 8-bit address bus for internal RAM out of which we just use 7 wires making it addressable to just 128 byte locations, why not use all 8 wires to make it accessible to 256 bytes?

Comment: Well, perhaps 7 wires for address, 1 wire for control (read/write, for example, similar to I2C which has 7 bits for device addresses, 1 bit for read/write). Another use of the single bit is for enable/disable "banks" of 128 bytes.

Comment: The 8051 was also a pretty early microcontroller; minimal RAM may have been a cost-cutting measure (though I have no actual evidence of this, merely a guess).

Answer (score 5):

There are 8051 compatibles with 256 bytes of RAM.

Original 8051 had 128 bytes because it was enough and the other 128 bytes are reserved for special function registers, so one address bit defines if you want to use RAM or SFS.

The chips with 256 bytes of RAM can only directly access 128 bytes because the other half is reserved for SFRs. The second half of RAM can only be accessed indirectly.

Comment: Most often, the second half of RAM is used for the stack.